# Emulate `perf record -g` with `perf_event_open`

Tags: c, linux, perf

My goal is to write some code to record the current call stack for all CPUs at some interval. Essentially I would like to do the same as `perf record` but using `perf_event_open` myself.

According to the manpage it seems I need to use the `PERF_SAMPLE_CALLCHAIN` sample type and read the results with `mmap`. That said, the manpage is incredibly terse, and some sample code would go a long way right now.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to learn about this would be to read the Linux kernel source code and see how you can emulate `perf record -g` yourself.

As you correctly identified, recording of `perf events` would start with the system call `perf_event_open`. So that is where we can start,

[definition of perf_event_open](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/events/core.c#L9862)

If you observe the parameters of the system call, you will see that the first parameter is a **struct perf_event_attr *** type. This is the parameter that takes in the attributes for the system call. This is what you need to modify to record callchains. A sample code could be like this (remember you can tweak other parameters and members of the struct perf_event_attr the way you want) :

```
     int buf_size_shift = 8;

     static unsigned perf_mmap_size(int buf_size_shift)
     {
       return ((1U << buf_size_shift) + 1) * sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
     }


     int main(int argc, char **argv)
     {

       struct perf_event_attr pe;
       long long count;
       int fd;

       memset(&pe, 0, sizeof(struct perf_event_attr));
       pe.type = PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE;
       pe.sample_type = PERF_SAMPLE_CALLCHAIN; /* this is what allows you to obtain callchains */

       pe.size = sizeof(struct perf_event_attr);
       pe.config = PERF_COUNT_HW_INSTRUCTIONS;
       pe.disabled = 1;
       pe.exclude_kernel = 1;
       pe.sample_period = 1000;
       pe.exclude_hv = 1;

       fd = perf_event_open(&pe, 0, -1, -1, 0); 
       if (fd == -1) {
          fprintf(stderr, "Error opening leader %llx\n", pe.config);
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       /* associate a buffer with the file */
       struct perf_event_mmap_page *mpage;
       mpage = mmap(NULL,  perf_mmap_size(buf_size_shift),
        PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED,
       fd, 0);
       if (mpage == (struct perf_event_mmap_page *)-1L) {
        close(fd);
        return -1;
       }

       ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET, 0);
       ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, 0);

       printf("Measuring instruction count for this printf\n");

       ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_DISABLE, 0);
       read(fd, &count, sizeof(long long));

       printf("Used %lld instructions\n", count);

       close(fd);
     }
```

**Note: A nice and easy way to understand the handling of all of these perf events can be seen below -**

[PMU-TOOLS by Andi Kleen](https://github.com/andikleen/pmu-tools)

If you start reading the source code for the system call, you will see that a function [perf_event_alloc](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/events/core.c#L9976) is being called. This function, among other things, will setup the buffer for obtaining callchains using `perf record`.

The function [get_callchain_buffers](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/events/core.c#L9546) is responsible for setting up callchain buffers.

`perf_event_open` works via a sampling/counting mechanism where if the performance monitoring counter corresponding to the event you are profiling overflows, then all the event relevant information will be collected and stored into a ring-buffer by the kernel. This ring-buffer can be prepared and accessed via `mmap(2)`.

Edit #1:

The flowchart describing the use of mmap when doing `perf record` is shown via the below image.

[image]

The process of mmaping ring buffers would start from the first function when you call `perf record` - which is [__cmd_record](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/tools/perf/builtin-record.c#L794), this calls [record__open](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/tools/perf/builtin-record.c#L332), which then calls [record__mmap](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/tools/perf/builtin-record.c#L327), followed by a call to [record__mmap_evlist](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/tools/perf/builtin-record.c#L298), which then calls [perf_evlist__mmap_ex](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/tools/perf/util/evlist.c#L1054), this is followed by [perf_evlist__mmap_per_cpu](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/tools/perf/util/evlist.c#L877) and finally ending up in [perf_evlist__mmap_per_evsel](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/tools/perf/util/evlist.c#L801) which is doing most of the heavy-lifting as far as doing an mmap for each event is concerned.

Edit #2:

Yes you are correct. When you set the sample period to be, say, a 1000, this means for every 1000th occurrence of the event(which by default is **cycles**), the kernel will record a sample of this event into this buffer. This means the `perf` counters will be set to 1000, so that it overflows at 0 and you get an interrupt and eventual recording of the samples.

Comment: This is a good answer, however one interesting part - reading from `mpage` - is missing. Would you be willing to extend the answer by that?

Comment: Really appreciate you taking the time to answer. A few things 1. I'm also interested in the code to access the mmaped ring buffer.
2. I also expected to see `pe.sample_freq` or `pe.sample_period` set to some value?
3. Can you confirm the interpretation of `pe.sample_period`: when combined with `PERF_COUNT_HW_INSTRUCTIONS` does this mean we sample every `pe.sample_period` retired instructions.